# Why is my implementation of rgeom faster than R's?

Tags: r, performance

I implemented my_rgeom function using that if X ~ Geom(p) and Y ~ Exp(-log(1 − p)) then Z=ceiling(Y) has same distribution as X. Using [inverse-transform method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) I can now define my function as:

```
my_rgeom <- function(N, p) {
    U <- runif(N)
    Y <- log(U) / log(1 - p)
    
    return(ceiling(Y))
}
```

Why is R's implementation not using for example inverse-transform since its much faster?

Results of benchmarking this vs the standard rgeom function:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

N <- 10^6
prob <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5) 

results_list <- list()

for (p in prob) {
    benchmark_results <- microbenchmark(
        my_rgeom(N, p),
        rgeom(N, p),
        times = 100  
    )
    
    # Store the results in the list
    results_list[[as.character(p)]] <- benchmark_results
}
# Plot the results for each value of p
plots <- lapply(prob, function(p) {
    autoplot(results_list[[as.character(p)]], title = paste("p =", p))
})

# Display the plots
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plots)
```

[Results of code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRFls.png)

And output of results_list:

```
results_list 
$`0.1`
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
 my_rgeom(N, p)  63.2907  69.1584  76.95829  73.62385  78.8459 172.4273   100
    rgeom(N, p) 115.0211 123.7101 131.01782 127.05655 134.2484 191.6843   100

$`0.2`
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 my_rgeom(N, p)  63.4618  76.8853  87.02115  85.91125  94.29075 195.5412   100
    rgeom(N, p) 117.3709 130.1152 142.02507 135.24175 148.68975 274.5087   100

$`0.3`
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 my_rgeom(N, p)  66.2584  77.31255  85.50857  81.4676  88.8424 178.2553   100
    rgeom(N, p) 115.3894 129.59360 139.56611 135.2741 146.1852 187.7755   100

$`0.4`
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 my_rgeom(N, p)  68.1903  75.1489  83.53151  80.1580  86.8057 180.0446   100
    rgeom(N, p) 116.3780 121.7696 132.27215 126.9434 137.8039 213.7012   100

$`0.5`
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 my_rgeom(N, p)  70.0728  73.63675  82.20571  79.3234  84.6281 178.6583   100
    rgeom(N, p) 116.5077 119.13275 126.49830 124.5081 130.1617 187.6423   100
```

Comment: Checking what's inside `rgeom` shows us that it's actually implemented in C. That makes these results way more surprising. If I had to guess, I would say `rgeom` performs some additional checks so that data is valid before running the formula.

Comment: I was also surprised by that (see https://github.com/atks/Rmath/blob/master/rgeom.c for what we're talking about). This -> https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/nmath/sexp.c is the C source code for exp_rand, which may be where some of the checks are happening.

Comment: R generates rgeom [using rpois](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f46b4cd47b4f4b2bb5ef40137a7f48f91b66469e/src/nmath/rgeom.c#L45). It's possible that method is more stable with floating point numbers. Even when things are mathematically equivalent, results can be different because computers actually aren't very good at math sometimes.

Comment: Is that method more stable?

Comment: BTW, are you using a different definition? (The R distribution has a support that includes 0, yours doesn't ... Wikipedia offers two different definitions depending on whether 0 is included or not ...)

Comment: Nice finding. Just a side note: `rgeom3 <- function(n, prob) as.integer(log(runif(n)) / log(1 - prob))` will be about 10% faster (and its support start at 0).

Comment: @BenBolker Yes the function I posted is the definition with support 1,2,... but its just shifting so doesn't really matter.

Comment: If `prob` is very small, e.g. `1e-20`, then the standard generator still works, but `my_rgeom` and `rgeom3` both fail, because `1 - prob == 1`.  You could fix this by using `log1p()`, but then there could be problems at the other extreme.  Once you start handling all the special cases, you slow down.

Comment: I'd check on the reference in the help page, but I don't have a copy of Devroye handy.  He probably discusses both generators.

Comment: @user2554330 the reference appears to be available here: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~mascagni/Devroye.pdf Page 480 on that reference is the end of a section of discussion related to the topic (and has homework problems more closely related).

Comment: Looks like a typo in the page reference on the help page.  I think the method is described on p 488ff, which is what the comment in the source mentions:  https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e1640b61ae48921500c025ce417b794ba2236b93/src/nmath/rgeom.c#L33.  This is for negative binomial, of which the geometric is a special case.

Comment: @user2554330 Is that really a problem? Could just add ```if prob>... then rgeom3 else rgeom``` at basically no cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The R implementation of `rgeom` appears to be treating the geometric distribution as a special case of the negative binomial distribution, which relies on Poisson random variates. I can see no reason for not using inverse transform sampling, as it will be faster and can be made to be just as numerically stable as `rgeom`. However, I would suggest a couple modifications to `my_rgeom`.

First, `-rexp(N)` will be faster than `log(runif(N))`. Second, to better handle very small values of `p`, `log1p(-p)` is preferred over `log(1 - p)`, as mentioned in the comments.

As a side note, `rgeom` has support starting at `0`, so I will use `floor` instead of `ceiling`.

The following code demonstrates the above.

First define some candidate functions:

```
set.seed(1845088186)

rgeom1 <- function(N, p) {
  U <- runif(N)
  Y <- log(U) / log(1 - p)
  return(floor(Y))
}

rgeom2 <- function(N, p) {
  floor(-rexp(N)/log(1 - p))
}

rgeom3 <- function(N, p) {
  floor(-rexp(N)/log1p(-p))
}

rgeom_all <- list(rgeom, rgeom1, rgeom2, rgeom3)
```

Test that they all return the same distribution.

```
(p <- runif(1))
#> [1] 0.08180412
x <- lapply(rgeom_all, \(f) f(1e6, p))

suppressWarnings(sapply(x[-1], \(y) ks.test(y, x[[1]])$p.value))
#> [1] 0.7088201 0.7734314 0.7856763
mapply(summary, x)
#>              [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#> Min.      0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
#> 1st Qu.   3.00000   3.00000   3.00000   3.00000
#> Median    8.00000   8.00000   8.00000   8.00000
#> Mean     11.23687  11.23102  11.21926  11.21025
#> 3rd Qu.  16.00000  16.00000  16.00000  16.00000
#> Max.    203.00000 187.00000 146.00000 171.00000
```

Compare timings:

```
p <- runif(1e6)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rgeom = rgeom(1e6, p),
  rgeom1 = rgeom1(1e6, p),
  rgeom2 = rgeom2(1e6, p),
  rgeom3 = rgeom3(1e6, p)
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>    expr     min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#>   rgeom 82.3725 91.00560 100.98802 100.48860 108.7335 146.5782   100
#>  rgeom1 64.3914 74.54830  82.31284  80.25625  87.1611 123.3017   100
#>  rgeom2 55.6838 60.14365  69.41881  66.87925  75.9065 143.6629   100
#>  rgeom3 53.8316 58.36640  65.48733  64.77050  70.4816 102.4296   100
```

Note that `log1p(-p)` is slightly faster than `log(1 - p)`.

However, the behavior of `rgeom` differs from that of the other three implementations when the variates are in the integer range:

```
sapply(rgeom_all, \(f) typeof(f(1, 0.5)))
#> [1] "integer" "double"  "double"  "double"
sapply(rgeom_all, \(f) typeof(f(1, .Machine$double.xmin)))
#> [1] "double" "double" "double" "double"
```

They also differ as to how they handle some invalid inputs:

```
rgeom(1, -0.5)
#> Warning in rgeom(1, -0.5): NAs produced
#> [1] NA
rgeom1(1, -0.5)
#> [1] -2
rgeom2(1, -0.5)
#> [1] -2
rgeom3(1, -0.5)
#> [1] -1

rgeom(1, 1.1)
#> Warning in rgeom(1, 1.1): NAs produced
#> [1] NA
rgeom1(1, 1.1)
#> Warning in log(1 - p): NaNs produced
#> [1] NaN
rgeom2(1, 1.1)
#> Warning in log(1 - p): NaNs produced
#> [1] NaN
rgeom3(1, 1.1)
#> Warning in log1p(-p): NaNs produced
#> [1] NaN

rgeom(1, NA)
#> Warning in rgeom(1, NA): NAs produced
#> [1] NA
rgeom1(1, NA)
#> [1] NA
rgeom2(1, NA)
#> [1] NA
rgeom3(1, NA)
#> [1] NA
```

The three candidate functions can be modified to mirror* the behavior of `rgeom` with some impact on performance:

(*Closely enough--fully and faithfully mirroring the behavior of `rgeom` in all cases will eliminate or even reverse the performance difference without resorting to C code.)

```
rgeom1 <- function(N, p) {
  if (length(p) == 1L && p[1] < 0) return(rep(NA_integer_, N))
  y <- log(runif(N))/log(1 - p)
  y[p < 0] <- NA_real_
  if (max(y, na.rm = 1) > .Machine$integer.max) floor(y) else as.integer(y)
}

rgeom2 <- function(N, p) {
  if (length(p) == 1L && p[1] < 0) return(rep(NA_integer_, N))
  y <- -rexp(N)/log(1 - p)
  y[p < 0] <- NA_real_
  if (max(y, na.rm = 1) > .Machine$integer.max) floor(y) else as.integer(y)
}

rgeom3 <- function(N, p) {
  if (length(p) == 1L && p[1] < 0) return(rep(NA_integer_, N))
  y <- -rexp(N)/log1p(-p)
  y[p < 0] <- NA_real_
  if (max(y, na.rm = 1) > .Machine$integer.max) floor(y) else as.integer(y)
}
```

Testing:

```
rgeom(1, -0.5)
#> Warning in rgeom(1, -0.5): NAs produced
#> [1] NA
rgeom1(1, -0.5)
#> Warning in max(y, na.rm = 1): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> [1] NA
rgeom2(1, -0.5)
#> Warning in max(y, na.rm = 1): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> [1] NA
rgeom3(1, -0.5)
#> Warning in max(y, na.rm = 1): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> [1] NA

rgeom(1, 1.1)
#> Warning in rgeom(1, 1.1): NAs produced
#> [1] NA
rgeom1(1, 1.1)
#> Warning in log(1 - p): NaNs produced
#> Warning in max(y, na.rm = 1): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> [1] NA
rgeom2(1, 1.1)
#> Warning in log(1 - p): NaNs produced

#> Warning in log(1 - p): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> [1] NA
rgeom3(1, 1.1)
#> Warning in log1p(-p): NaNs produced

#> Warning in log1p(-p): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> [1] NA

rgeom(1, NA)
#> Warning in rgeom(1, NA): NAs produced
#> [1] NA
rgeom1(1, NA)
#> Warning in max(y, na.rm = 1): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> [1] NA
rgeom2(1, NA)
#> Warning in max(y, na.rm = 1): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> [1] NA
rgeom3(1, NA)
#> Warning in max(y, na.rm = 1): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> [1] NA
```

Timing:

```
p <- runif(1e6, -0.1, 1.1)
p[sample(1e6, 1e3)] <- NA

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rgeom = rgeom(1e6, p),
  rgeom1 = rgeom1(1e6, p),
  rgeom2 = rgeom2(1e6, p),
  rgeom3 = rgeom3(1e6, p)
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>    expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>   rgeom 70.8633 72.26875 74.56052 73.36910 75.60830  88.3045   100
#>  rgeom1 65.1287 69.38690 74.28986 71.11060 73.09685 114.2515   100
#>  rgeom2 58.2231 62.40600 65.61609 64.12870 65.65905  99.9390   100
#>  rgeom3 58.9580 63.21480 68.88956 64.88055 66.62870 116.3178   100
```

However, for very small values of `p`, `rgeom1` and `rgeom2` are not well behaved:

```
sapply(rgeom_all, \(f) sum(is.finite(f(1e6, .Machine$double.xmin))))
#> Warning in f(1e+06, .Machine$double.xmin): NAs produced
#> [1] 981778      0      0 981709
```

`rgeom3` is well behaved over all values of `p` in addition to being the fastest of the four implementations.

Comment: Great answer. In your final functions you should type ```y[p <= 0]``` not ```y[p < 0]``` to match the output of ```rgeom(1,0)```, which gives NA.

Comment: Good eye, but that was actually intentional since the mean of the distribution goes to `Inf` as `p` approaches 0. Sources vary on whether the distribution is defined on `p=0` and `p=1` (Wikipedia, for example, defines the negative binomial for `0≤p≤1`, but the geometric for `0<p≤1` even though the latter is a special case of the former). Personally, I feel that returning `Inf` for `p=0` is more appropriate than `NA` when working with finite precision. As I said, the functions mirror the behavior of `rgeom` "closely enough".

Answer (score 4):

@jblood94's answer is great, I'm going to try to address the "why?" part of this, from a historical perspective.

- the `rgeom` code is 26 years old (see [git blame](https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blame/0131948d365e1d98c80fc518cbcb3f743eae071b/src/nmath/rgeom.c#L45)); in 1997, people were much less likely to be concerned specifically about the time taken to generate 1 million geometric deviates (even today, you need to be picking a *lot* of deviates before the difference between 75 and 150 milliseconds to pick 1 million deviates becomes important ...)
- `?rgeom` refers to Devroye (1986) *Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation* p. 480:

> ‘rgeom’ uses the derivation as an exponential mixture of Poissons, see Devroye ...

p. 480 seems as though it might be a typo (it's the exercises on continuous univariate distributions): maybe this should have been p. 488 (discussing the negative binomial as a mixture of Poissons: the geometric is a special case)?

It's a little weird, and presumably an oversight, because [pages 499-500](http://luc.devroye.org/chapter_ten.pdf) specifically discuss faster generation of geometric deviates.

If you can make a reasonable case for the value of this improvement (i.e. is it worth R-core's time to pull this method into base R, with the potential backward compatibility issues?), it would be worth discussing on `r-devel@r-project.org` ...

Comment: I think the back compatibility issues will torpedo the change.  It's a small speedup in absolute terms, and it will mean any tests involving `rgeom()` will produce different results.  That's not just work for R Core, it's work for CRAN and package authors and people trying to reproduce published results because `rgeom()` results will change.